# clang: error: no such file or directory: Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, carthage

> clang: error: no such file or directory:
> '/Users/xujun/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SimplifiedR2-cqmftumxfrylwdgmkcovwahjhquk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRDServices.a'
> Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code

Xcode 13.4.

My project won´t run after adding framework by Carthage. How to solve this error?

[image: error message]